# laravel encrypt decrypt password with secret key

Tags: php, security, encryption

We want to develop a software.Where thousand of user can store there facebook password, gmail password and linkedin password and that should be encrypted.key should be only with the user not in the server.How can we do that

Comment: Why do you want to encrypt and decrypt password in the first place? Using hash is considered more secure than encrypt/decrypt password.

Comment: I'm  trying to create password manager software where should have decrypt key for decrypt the password. If i'm using hash then I wont be able to decrypt password.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt` to encrypt and decrypt string.

Learn more about [Laravel Encryption](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/encryption)

You can encrypt a string like this

```
$encrypted_string = Crypt::encryptString("Sample String");
```

And you can decrypt a crypted string like this

```
$decrypted_string = Crypt::decryptString($encrypted_string);
```

The key will be taken from a global configuration variable in your app.